# How to exclude certain files in `ls`?

Tags: bash, ls

I would like to run `ls` and exclude certain files in the output.

When I run the following command, I get all files, each on a separate line:

```
$ ls -1
file1
file2
file3
temp
```

I would like to run this command in a way so that it shows:

```
$ ls -1 <insert magic here> temp
file1
file2
file3
```

Comment: `-1` Force output to be one entry per line.  This is the default when output is not to a terminal

Answer (score 158, accepted):

```
ls -I <filename>
```

`-I`: Ignore the filename, i.e. don't list the specified file.

To ignore more than one file add a `-I` before each filename.

```
ls -I file1 -I file2
```

To ignore files by their name extensions do the following, for example.

```
ls -I "*.jpg" -I "*.svg"
```

Comment: If you use the long-form option `--ignore` you can extend that to glob patterns e.g. `ls --ignore="file?"` or `ls --ignore="file*"`

Comment: you can use glob patterns with the short form as well by quoting the patterns

Comment: you can even use glob patterns *without* quotes, but by escaping the special letters: `ls -I \*.jpg` (tested in bash)

Answer (score 28):

For me, if I use `-I` once, it works, but if I use twice it doesn't.
E.g:

- This works:

  ```
  ls -I *.csv
  ```
- But:

  ```
  ls -I *.csv -I *.txt
  ```

  doesn't work and returns `.txt` files instead.

`--ignore` did the trick for me. This is what I needed and worked:

```
ls -lhrt --ignore="*.gz" --ignore="*.1"
```

The above will list files from my `log` folder excluding old backup logs.

Comment: quoting *.csv in the first form works, e.g.., `ls -I '*.txt'`. The reason it doesn't work unquoted is because of shell expansion, i.e. you're telling the shell to list all csv files instead of excluding them. What's actually happening is that it ignores the first .csv and .1 files after expansion, but lists the remainders

Comment: Double-quoting worked for me as well. Thanks @verboze

Answer (score 19):

You can also use:

```
ls --ignore={"*.jpg","*.png","*.svg"}
```

Comment: This is simply using bash's brace expansion to get three `--ignore` options. You could have also used `--ignore="*."{jpg,png,svg}`

Answer (score 7):

I think that this produces the output you're looking for:

```
ls -1 !(temp)
```

Apparently, [you need `shopt -s extglob`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889744/what-is-the-purpose-of-shopt-s-extglob) for that to work (I have it enabled, so I guess some time in the distant past I found it useful and enabled it).

I guess you could also use `grep` to filter the output:

```
ls -1 | grep -v '^temp$'
```

Using a pipe and filters provides a lot more flexibility, and skills that are transferable to other commands/situations, though you might not be interested in that for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe anyone else has mentioned the use of the `--hide` parameter with `ls`. It can be done as such:

```
ls --hide=*.jpg
```

If you want to pass in multiple --hide arguments just do:

```
ls --hide=*some_pattern* --hide=*some_other_pattern*
```

Comment: What's so hard to believe? This is pretty much the same as `--ignore` mentioned in multiple answers.

Comment: When I say "I don't believe" in this scenario of English it means "I don't think". You're thinking of "I can't believe". I am just showing there are other options. :)