# What is the purpose of shopt -s extglob

Tags: command-line, bash

I wanted to delete all the files from a directory except one. I found my solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624441/how-to-delete-all-files-except-one-named-file-from-a-specific-folder#answer-624445). This solution is using this command:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

I want to know what this command exactly does, some back end knowledge.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In simple terms, globbing refers to pattern matching. Bash uses simple globbing like, `echo l*` which expand to list of files in current directory that start with letter `l`.  Of course , as you can guess, it's simple and limited.

Enter `extglob`. As you can guess, it stands for `extended globbing`. This option allows for more advanced pattern matching. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash):

```
extglob If set, the extended pattern matching features described
        above under Pathname Expansion are enabled.
```

And  a little before that:

```
If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the  following
description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using  one  or  more  of  the
following sub-patterns:

      ?(pattern-list)
             Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
      *(pattern-list)
             Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
      +(pattern-list)
             Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
      @(pattern-list)
             Matches one of the given patterns
      !(pattern-list)
             Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

There's multitude of ways in which `extglob` can be used. Quite a few good examples are provided in [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) and [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob).

Comment: Is this a permanent change?  Is there a way to turn it off after I am done?

Comment: Right after I commented, I found shopt -u extglob to unset it.  I still wonder how long it lasts.

Comment: If you want it permanent [you need to add it into your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`)](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Setting_shell_options#Customizing_Bash_environment_with_shopt_and_set). The set option should be reset when closing the terminal or exiting the shell.