# Use chown -R while excluding one or two files

Tags: command-line, chown

How can I use `chown -R` but exclude one or two files?

I periodically need to run

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *
```

and

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu *
```

But I'd like to exclude one or two files from those commands as to not change the permissions of those excluded files.

How can I exclude `file1.php`, or both `file2.txt` and `file3.php`?

Comment: Could you consider allowing permission change on all files, and then reinstating the permissions for those two files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `bash`’s `extglob` option with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

and use it like that to exclude these files:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data !(file1.php)
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu !(file2.txt|file3.php)
```

This works with files and directories equally, but only in the current directory. If you need to exclude files in subdirectories, combine the above with the `globstar` option (`shopt -s globstar`):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data **/!(file1.php)
```

This matches every file and directory except the ones called `file1.php`.

#### Example run

```
$ touch {1..3}
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo !(1)
2 3
$ echo !(1|2)
3
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/{1..3}
$ tree
.
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
└── a
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    └── 3
$ shopt -s globstar
$ echo **/!(1|2)
3 a a/3
```

#### Further reading

- [`man bash`/EXPANSION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion)/Pathname Expansion/Pattern Matching
- [What is the purpose of shopt -s extglob](https://askubuntu.com/q/889744/507051)
- [bash-hackers.org: Extended pattern language](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language)