# Counting files in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I use the following code at the end of one of my scripts to tally up the number of files I have processed and moved into that directory.

```
# Report on Current Status
echo -n "Cropped Files: "
ls "${Destination}" | wc -l
```

My problem lies with how I handle duplicate files.  As of right now, I check for the file's presence first (as my script is destructive in nature to the source files I am processing).  If it senses a file of that name already processed, I alter the filename as follows.

Duplicate file: foo.pdf

Changed name: foo.x.pdf

If there is a foo.x.pdf, then I rename again to foo.xx.pdf.  Repeat as necessary.  I intend to go in later and evaluate each 'version' and select the best one to keep on hand.  But herein lies my problem.  I would like to count the number of files that do not contain .x. .xx. and so on.  How do I strip these out of the `ls` output so `wc -l` can count the unique files only?

TL;DR: How do I get the count of files in a given directory that do not contain a given substring in their filename?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find the number of files in a directory that do not contain `.x.pdf`, try:

```
find "${Destination}" -mindepth 1 ! -name '*.x.pdf' -printf '1' | wc -c
```

To find the number of files in a directory that do not contain period - one or more `x` - period - `pdf`, try:

```
find "${Destination}" -mindepth 1 ! -regex '.*\.x+\.pdf' -printf '1' | wc -c
```

The above search recursively through subdirectories.  If you don't want that, add the option `-maxdepth 1`.  For example:

```
find "${Destination}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -regex '.*\.x+\.pdf' -printf '1' | wc -c
```

Note that because we use `-printf '1'`, this method is safe even if the directory contains files whose names contain newline characters.

Comment: Altered your second example and tested it.  Works!  Thank you.  find "${Destination}" -mindepth 1 ! -regex '.*\.x+\.pdf' -printf '1\n' | wc -l

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes, that does seem simpler.  Answer updated to eliminate `\n`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without subdirectories:

```
echo $(($(for file in *.sh ; do echo -n 1+; done; echo 0;)))
```

because:

```
for file in *.sh ; do echo -n 1+; done; echo 0;
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+0
```

Comment: I see how this counts files in a directory but how does it avoid counting the files that the OP doesn't want to count: _"But herein lies my problem. I would like to count the number of files that do not contain .x. .xx. and so on"_?

Comment: @John1024: Count all files, count all files with .x*.pdf, subtract.

Comment: user-unknown, OK.  Very good.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude a file or files that match to a pattern from the `ls` command by using (one or more times) the option `-I`, `--ignore=PATTERN` ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512961/exclude-certain-files-in-ls)):

```
ls -I "*.x*.pdf" "${Destination}" | wc -l
```

Or you could use the subtraction method in this way:

```
echo $(($(ls "${Destination}" | wc -l) - $(ls "${Destination}"/*.x*.pdf | wc -l)))
```